# Find first day of first group of six consecutive days per year and coordinate?

Tags: r, count, statistics

I'm new to R and need some advise solving the following problem: I have a .dbf table in a data frame with dates on which a certain threshold is passed on different spatial locations which are indicated by a "PointID" in that table. It looks like this:

```
time    PointID
04/07/71    X10Y11
04/25/71    X10Y11
04/26/71    X10Y11
05/02/71    X10Y11
05/03/71    X10Y11
05/04/71    X10Y11
05/05/71    X10Y11
05/09/71    X10Y11
05/12/71    X10Y11
05/13/71    X10Y11
05/14/71    X10Y11
05/15/71    X10Y11
05/16/71    X10Y11
05/17/71    X10Y11
05/18/71    X10Y11
05/19/71    X10Y11
05/20/71    X10Y11
05/21/71    X10Y11
05/22/71    X10Y11
05/23/71    X10Y11
05/26/71    X10Y11
10/07/71    X10Y11
10/08/71    X10Y11
10/09/71    X10Y11
10/10/71    X10Y11
10/11/71    X10Y11
10/12/71    X10Y11
10/23/71    X10Y11
10/24/71    X10Y11
10/25/71    X10Y11
10/26/71    X10Y11
10/27/71    X10Y11
10/28/71    X10Y11
11/04/71    X10Y11
03/30/72    X10Y11
04/07/72    X10Y11
04/08/72    X10Y11
04/10/72    X10Y11
04/20/72    X10Y11
04/22/72    X10Y11
04/23/72    X10Y11
04/24/72    X10Y11
04/25/72    X10Y11
04/26/72    X10Y11
04/27/72    X10Y11
04/28/72    X10Y11
04/29/72    X10Y11
04/30/72    X10Y11
05/01/72    X10Y11
05/02/72    X10Y11
05/03/72    X10Y11
05/08/72    X10Y11
05/09/72    X10Y11
05/10/72    X10Y11
05/11/72    X10Y11
10/09/72    X10Y11
10/10/72    X10Y11
10/11/72    X10Y11
10/12/72    X10Y11
10/13/72    X10Y11
10/14/72    X10Y11
10/15/72    X10Y11
10/16/72    X10Y11
10/17/72    X10Y11
10/18/72    X10Y11
10/19/72    X10Y11
01/15/73    X10Y11
01/21/73    X10Y11
03/19/73    X10Y11
03/20/73    X10Y11
03/21/73    X10Y11
03/31/73    X10Y11
04/01/73    X10Y11
04/02/73    X10Y11
04/03/73    X10Y11
04/15/73    X10Y11
03/01/71    X10Y12
04/04/71    X10Y12
04/07/71    X10Y12
04/08/71    X10Y12
04/09/71    X10Y12
04/10/71    X10Y12
04/11/71    X10Y12
04/18/71    X10Y12
04/19/71    X10Y12
04/20/71    X10Y12
04/21/71    X10Y12
04/22/71    X10Y12
04/23/71    X10Y12
04/25/71    X10Y12
04/26/71    X10Y12
04/28/71    X10Y12
05/02/71    X10Y12
05/03/71    X10Y12
05/04/71    X10Y12
05/05/71    X10Y12
05/06/71    X10Y12
05/07/71    X10Y12
05/08/71    X10Y12
05/09/71    X10Y12
05/10/71    X10Y12
07/08/71    X10Y12
07/09/71    X10Y12
07/10/71    X10Y12
07/11/71    X10Y12
07/12/71    X10Y12
11/02/71    X10Y12
11/03/71    X10Y12
11/04/71    X10Y12
02/10/72    X10Y12
02/11/72    X10Y12
03/30/72    X10Y12
04/05/72    X10Y12
04/06/72    X10Y12
04/07/72    X10Y12
04/08/72    X10Y12
04/10/72    X10Y12
04/23/72    X10Y12
04/24/72    X10Y12
04/25/72    X10Y12
04/26/72    X10Y12
04/27/72    X10Y12
04/28/72    X10Y12
04/29/72    X10Y12
04/30/72    X10Y12
05/01/72    X10Y12
05/02/72    X10Y12
05/03/72    X10Y12
05/04/72    X10Y12
05/07/72    X10Y12
05/08/72    X10Y12
05/09/72    X10Y12
05/10/72    X10Y12
05/11/72    X10Y12
05/12/72    X10Y12
05/13/72    X10Y12
05/14/72    X10Y12
05/15/72    X10Y12
05/16/72    X10Y12
05/17/72    X10Y12
08/30/72    X10Y12
08/31/72    X10Y12
09/01/72    X10Y12
09/02/72    X10Y12
09/03/72    X10Y12
09/04/72    X10Y12
09/05/72    X10Y12
09/06/72    X10Y12
```

Now I'm looking for a way to find the first day of the first group of six consecutive days per year and PointID. The result for the table above would ideally look something like this, with only the dates and PointIDs remaining:

```
time    PointID
05/12/71    X10Y11
04/22/72    X10Y11
04/18/71    X10Y12
04/23/72    X10Y12
```

The solution should work on large datasets of 7+ millions of rows per table. Does anyone know a solution to this problem and can help me out?

Thank you!

EDIT: variables are as follows

```
'data.frame':   21071 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ time   : Date, format: "1971-03-01" "1971-04-04" "1971-04-04" "1971-04-04" ...
 $ PointID: Factor w/ 5 levels "X10Y11","X10Y12",..: 2 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 5 2 ...
```

Comment: It seems like this question contains several distinct questions. The easy bit is "how do you get a result by by year and point?". For that there are lots of solutions. (You probably want `dplyr`'s `group_by()` function. The other, harder part is "how do you find if a vector contains n consecutive values?".

Comment: What type of column is "time" ? Date ? POSIXct... ?

Comment: @Richie Cotton: Yes, I guess so. I've seen group_by() in similiar questions, but couldn't adapt it.

Comment: @digEmAll: Yes, it's "Date", at least it is recognized as date in Excel etc.

Comment: @Chr.Hnm: mmh... I guess it's a character or factor actually.... you should post the result of `str(yourDataFrame)`

Comment: @digEmAll: It's "Date", see updated question above.

Comment: @Chr.Hnm: my bad, thanks for the clarification ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if efficient enough, but this is a possible solution in base R :

```
DF$year <- as.integer(format(DF$time,format='%Y'))

findFirstConsecutiveSixDays <- function(dates){
  dates <- sort(dates)
  RLE <- rle(as.numeric(dates[-length(dates)] - dates[-1]))
  groupOfSixConsec <- which(RLE$values == -1 & RLE$lengths >= 5)
  if(length(groupOfSixConsec) == 0)
    return(as.Date(NA))
  D <- dates[sum(RLE$lengths[1:groupOfSixConsec[1]])-RLE$lengths[groupOfSixConsec[1]]+1]
  return(D)
}

Grouped <- aggregate(time ~ year + PointID, DF, FUN=findFirstConsecutiveSixDays)

> Grouped[complete.cases(Grouped),c('time','PointID')]
        time PointID
1 1971-05-12  X10Y11
2 1972-04-22  X10Y11
4 1971-04-18  X10Y12
5 1972-04-23  X10Y12
```

---

Code to replicate the DF :

```
DF <- structure(list(time = structure(c(461, 479, 480, 486, 487, 488, 
489, 493, 496, 497, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 
507, 510, 644, 645, 646, 647, 648, 649, 660, 661, 662, 663, 664, 
665, 672, 819, 827, 828, 830, 840, 842, 843, 844, 845, 846, 847, 
848, 849, 850, 851, 852, 853, 858, 859, 860, 861, 1012, 1013, 
1014, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1019, 1020, 1021, 1022, 1110, 1116, 
1173, 1174, 1175, 1185, 1186, 1187, 1188, 1200, 424, 458, 461, 
462, 463, 464, 465, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 479, 480, 482, 
486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 493, 494, 553, 554, 555, 556, 
557, 670, 671, 672, 770, 771, 819, 825, 826, 827, 828, 830, 843, 
844, 845, 846, 847, 848, 849, 850, 851, 852, 853, 854, 857, 858, 
859, 860, 861, 862, 863, 864, 865, 866, 867, 972, 973, 974, 975, 
976, 977, 978, 979), class = "Date"), PointID = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("X10Y11", "X10Y12"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("time", 
"PointID"), row.names = c(NA, -148L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This worked! I can duplicate the result for your data frame as well as for a sample of my data (21,000 rows). Later on I will test it on a complete table of 7+ million rows and worry about efficiency ;) Thank you for your help!

Comment: It also worked on the large table and took only about a minute for 6.5 million rows. Splendid! A question concerning your code: if I wanted a period of ten consecutive days, I would change the line "groupOfSixConsec <- which(RLE$values == -1 & RLE$lengths >= 5)" to "groupOfSixConsec <- which(RLE$values == -1 & RLE$lengths >= 9)", right?

Comment: @Chr.Hnm : yep exactly

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea using `tidyverse`,

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(PointID) %>% 
  mutate(new = c(NA, diff.difftime(time)), new1 = data.table::rleid(new)) %>% 
  filter(new == 1) %>% 
  group_by(PointID, new1) %>% 
  summarise(cnt = n(), time = first(time)) %>% 
  filter(cnt >= 5) %>% 
  mutate(time = time - 1) %>% 
  group_by(PointID, time1 = format(time, format = '%Y')) %>% 
  slice(1L) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-c(new1, cnt, time1))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  PointID       time
#   <fctr>     <date>
#1  X10Y11 1971-05-12
#2  X10Y11 1972-04-22
#3  X10Y12 1971-04-18
#4  X10Y12 1972-04-23
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I get an error message saying: Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: Hmm.. works as expected on my system. What versions of R, dplyr are you using?

Comment: I'm using R x64 3.4.1 and dplyr 0.7.1

Comment: Not sure either. Thank you anyway!